# How to know if webkitSpeechRecognition is started?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkitspeechrecognition

I'm making a bot to listen to my voice.
So i did :

```
this.recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
```

I can do this to start listen :

```
this.recognition.start();
```

And this to stop listen :

```
this.recognition.stop();
```

But do you know a function that will return me true if `this.recognition` is started and false if it's stopped ? Like `"isStarted()"` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by raising a flag variable on the `onstart` and `onend` events:

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
var recognizing = false;

recognition.onstart = function () {
    recognizing = true;
};

recognition.onend = function () {
    recognizing = false;
};

recognition.onerror = function (event) {
    recognizing = false;
};

if (recognizing) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already tryed it. My code is a little bit complex so sometimes it's crashing with this error : ------ > Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'start' on 'SpeechRecognition': recognition has already started. I can miss a boolean update anywhere but a webkitSpeechRecognition function is a better solution :P

Comment: @TomSkat There is no boolean value currently, so you would have to implement one like I wrote. Please add the `onerror` event like I edited in my answer, and wrap your code with `catch`, that should solve the case you mentioned as well.

Comment: It seem's to be ok :p, cause i don't put the boolean edit in events ;)

Comment: @TomSkat Wonderful. I am doing this myself and it works great. Hope I helped.

Answer (score -1):

You can simple check this

```
if(this.recognition){
    //do something if true
}else{
    // do something else if false
}
```